# preserve mtime of files and directories while doing a copy with scp -r from remote server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am doing a clean up activity on files based on the time with which they create , however I also have to take a backup with scp without modifying the ctime or mtime of files

Later I will use find command to pick the qualified files with mtime in my shells script

```
find  $V_Filepath -mmin +7200 -name "*.ack"
```

Comment: See: `man scp | grep time`

Answer (score 2):

To keep the mtime unchanged scp -p option would help in terms of doing scp between two servers.

eg:

```
scp -pr myfile.* username@server://path/
```

Comparing the mtime (using stat command) before and after remains same.  scp -p option preserves the mtime of the files

eg:

```
stat -c '%y' myfile.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Modification time is the `mtime`, not `ctime`. `scp -p` already preserves mtime.

ctime is the inode change time, updated every time the file itself is touched in any way – renamed, moved, chmodded, etc.

Generally, there is no way to preserve it, as the OS does not provide any function for that, and even if it did, the very act of setting the ctime would be a change that would cause the ctime to be updated again.